# PyTorch LSTM not learning in training

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following simple LSTM network:

```
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.layer_dim = layer_dim
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
        self.batch_size = None
        self.hidden = None
    
    def forward(self, x):
        h0, c0 = self.init_hidden(x)
        out, (hn, cn) = self.rnn(x, (h0, c0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out
    
    def init_hidden(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim)
        return [t for t in (h0, c0)]
```

I am initialising this model as"

```
model = LSTMClassifier(28, 10, 6, 1)
```

i.e. each input instance has 6 time steps and the dimension of each time step is 28, and the hidden dimension is 10. The inputs are being mapped to an output dim of 1.

The training data is being prepared in batches of size 16, meaning that the data passed in the training loop has the shape:

```
torch.Size([16, 6, 28])
```

With labels of shape:

```
batches[1][0].size()
```

An example of the input is:

```
tensor([[-0.3674,  0.0347, -0.2169, -0.0821, -0.3673, -0.1773,  1.1840, -0.2669,
         -0.4202, -0.1473, -0.1132, -0.4756, -0.3565,  0.5010,  0.1274, -0.1147,
          0.2783,  0.0836, -1.3251, -0.8067, -0.6447, -0.7396, -0.3241,  1.3329,
          1.3801,  0.8198,  0.6098,  0.0697],
        [-0.2710,  0.1596, -0.2524, -0.0821, -0.3673, -0.1773,  0.0302, -0.2099,
         -0.4550,  0.1451, -0.4561, -0.5207, -0.5657, -0.5287, -0.2690, -0.1147,
         -0.0346, -0.1043, -0.7515, -0.8392, -0.4745, -0.7396, -0.3924,  0.8122,
         -0.1624, -1.2198,  0.0326, -0.9306],
        [-0.1746,  0.0972, -0.2702, -0.0821, -0.3673, -0.1773, -0.0468, -1.1225,
         -0.4480, -0.4397,  0.4011, -1.1073, -1.0536, -0.1855, -0.7502, -0.1147,
         -0.0146, -0.1545, -0.1919, -0.1674,  0.0930, -0.7396,  0.8106,  1.1594,
          0.4546, -1.2198, -0.5446, -1.2640],
        [-0.2710,  0.0660, -0.2524, -0.0821, -0.4210, -0.1773,  1.8251, -0.5236,
         -0.4410, -0.7321,  0.4011, -0.6110, -0.2171,  1.1875, -0.2973, -0.1147,
         -0.1278,  0.7728, -0.9334, -0.5141, -2.1202,  1.3521, -0.9393,  0.5085,
         -0.4709,  0.8198, -1.1218,  0.0697],
        [-0.3674, -0.0277, -0.2347, -0.0821, -0.0448, -0.1773,  0.2866, -0.1386,
         -0.4271,  0.4375, -0.2847, -0.1146, -0.4262, -0.3571, -0.0425, -0.1147,
         -0.4207, -0.4552, -0.5277, -0.9584, -0.4177, -0.7396, -0.2967,  0.5085,
          0.4546, -1.2198, -0.3522, -1.2640],
        [-0.3674, -0.1447, -0.1991, -0.0821,  0.1701, -0.1773,  0.0430,  0.1324,
         -0.4271,  0.7299, -0.4561,  0.2915, -0.5657, -0.1855, -0.2123, -0.1147,
         -0.0413, -0.8311, -0.6396, -1.0451, -0.4177, -0.7396, -0.2967, -0.4028,
          0.7631, -1.2198, -0.3522, -1.2640]])
```

When I train the model as:

```
Epochs = 10
batch_size = 32
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=5e-4)
for epoch in range(Epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}")
    for n, (X, y) in enumerate(batches):
        model.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(X)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


    model.eval()
    accurate = 0
    for X_instance, y_instance in zip(test_X, test_y):
        if y_instance == round(model(X_instance.view(-1, 6, 28)).detach().item()):
            accurate += 1
    print(f"Accuracy test set: {accurate/len(test_X)}")
```

The accuracy does not converge:

```
Epoch 1
Accuracy test set: 0.23169107856191745
Sample params: 
tensor([-0.3356, -0.0105, -0.3405, -0.0049,  0.0037,  0.1707,  0.2685, -0.3893,
        -0.4707, -0.2872, -0.1544, -0.1455,  0.0393,  0.0774, -0.4194,  0.0780,
        -0.2177, -0.3829, -0.4679,  0.0370, -0.0794,  0.0455, -0.1331, -0.0169,
        -0.1551, -0.0348,  0.1746, -0.5163], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor([ 0.2137, -0.2558,  0.1509, -0.0975,  0.5591,  0.0907, -0.1249,  0.3095,
         0.2112,  0.3134, -0.1581, -0.3051, -0.3559, -0.0177,  0.1485,  0.4397,
        -0.1441,  0.1705,  0.3230, -0.3236,  0.0692,  0.0920, -0.2691, -0.3695,
        -0.0692,  0.3747,  0.0149,  0.5216], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
Epoch 2
Accuracy test set: 0.23049267643142476
Sample params: 
tensor([-0.3483, -0.0144, -0.3512,  0.0213, -0.0081,  0.1777,  0.2674, -0.4031,
        -0.4628, -0.3041, -0.1651, -0.1511,  0.0216,  0.0513, -0.4320,  0.0839,
        -0.2602, -0.3629, -0.4541,  0.0398, -0.0768,  0.0432, -0.1150, -0.0160,
        -0.1346, -0.0727,  0.1801, -0.5253], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor([ 0.1879, -0.2534,  0.1461, -0.1141,  0.5735,  0.0872, -0.1286,  0.3273,
         0.2084,  0.3037, -0.1535, -0.2934, -0.3870, -0.0252,  0.1492,  0.4752,
        -0.1709,  0.1776,  0.3390, -0.3318,  0.0734,  0.1077, -0.2790, -0.3777,
        -0.0518,  0.3726,  0.0228,  0.5404], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
Epoch 3
Accuracy test set: 0.22982689747003995
Sample params: 
tensor([-0.3725, -0.0069, -0.3623,  0.0393, -0.0167,  0.1748,  0.2577, -0.4183,
        -0.4681, -0.3196, -0.1657, -0.1613,  0.0122,  0.0268, -0.4361,  0.0838,
        -0.2962, -0.3566, -0.4344,  0.0366, -0.0822,  0.0486, -0.1150, -0.0295,
        -0.1080, -0.1094,  0.1841, -0.5336], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor([ 0.1664, -0.2456,  0.1477, -0.1332,  0.5820,  0.0819, -0.1228,  0.3426,
         0.2066,  0.2985, -0.1464, -0.2824, -0.4199, -0.0323,  0.1530,  0.5057,
        -0.1991,  0.1856,  0.3407, -0.3347,  0.0800,  0.1203, -0.2791, -0.3863,
        -0.0426,  0.3760,  0.0327,  0.5641], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
Epoch 4
Accuracy test set: 0.23249001331557922
Sample params: 
tensor([-0.3945,  0.0032, -0.3765,  0.0600, -0.0248,  0.1713,  0.2442, -0.4297,
        -0.4741, -0.3311, -0.1653, -0.1667,  0.0029,  0.0066, -0.4373,  0.0738,
        -0.3320, -0.3530, -0.4136,  0.0390, -0.0731,  0.0552, -0.1117, -0.0517,
        -0.0871, -0.1455,  0.1841, -0.5359], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor([ 0.1495, -0.2292,  0.1524, -0.1473,  0.5938,  0.0661, -0.1157,  0.3626,
         0.2013,  0.2927, -0.1350, -0.2661, -0.4558, -0.0411,  0.1562,  0.5381,
        -0.2279,  0.1927,  0.3319, -0.3431,  0.0852,  0.1402, -0.2747, -0.4026,
        -0.0297,  0.3757,  0.0396,  0.5856], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

Have I made a mistake in the model definition?

Comment: What is the value of the loss during the training? Another thing you can check is if the value of your model parameters are changing by checking `model.parameters()`

Comment: Lots of code seems to be missing. For all we know, all your inputs could be zero. What happens with the gradients then? Please provide a complete and minimal example illustrating the problem.

Comment: Have updated the question - there is some convergence but it is slow - is this to be expected?

Answer (score 2):

So normally 6 layers in your LSTM are way to much. The input dimension is 28 (are you training MNIST, or are the inputs letters?) so 10 as hidden dimension is acutally way to small. Try the following parameters:

```
hidden_dim = 128 to 512
layer_dim = 2 to max. 4
```

I see your output-shape is 1 and you dont use an activation function. Are you trying to predict intergers (like 1 for class "dog", 2 for class "cat")? If so you should switch to one-hot encoding, so that your output shape is equal to the classes you want to predict. And then use softmax as activation for your last layer.

Comment: The problem isn't MNIST, just happens to also have dimension 28 haha

Comment: It's a timeseries regression problem, with the 28 variables in the input being non-linearly related to the targets

Comment: The targets are integers between 0 and 20

Comment: did you change all the stuff I suggested? Did it improve?

Comment: I ran into some other problems with the gpu but will let you know what the outcome is. Could adding more layers be beneficial do you think (you seem as though you may be knowledgable about recurrent nets)?

Comment: so you used 6 layers in your LSTM which acutally is too much, as I said, try 2 layers. But you can try to ad another fc layer after the LSTM. And make sure to use softmax activation + one-hot encoding